# Screen switching by press on button react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, switching

I just started to learn React-native. In this app I have a two buttons in header, first 'Todo', second 'Tags'. I want to chang content by press on these buttons. I think I need to change state.[for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofFTs.png)What I mean, when i tap on the button Tags, below I get TagScreen component, exactly the same for the button Todo. How to connect these components so that they work correctly?

app.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet,  View, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { Navbar } from './src/Navbar'
import { TagScreen } from './src/screens/TagScreen'
import { TodoScreen } from './src/screens/TodoScreen'



export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
  const [appId, setAppId] = useState([])

  const addTodo = title => {
    setTodos(prev => [
      ...prev,
      {
        id: Date.now().toString(),
        title
      }
    ])
  }

  const addTags = title => {
    setTags(prev => [
      ...prev,
      {
        id: Date.now().toString(),
        title
      }
    ])
  }

  const removeTags = id => {
    setTags(prev => prev.filter(tag => tag.id !== id))
  }
  const removeTodo = id => {
    setTodos(prev => prev.filter(todo => todo.id !== id))
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Navbar title='Todo App!' />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TagScreen addTags={addTags} tags={tags} removeTags={removeTags}/>
        {/* <TodoScreen todos={todos} addTodo={addTodo} removeTodo={removeTodo} /> */}
        {/* HERE MUST CHANGED COMPONENTS */}
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    paddingVertical: 20
  }
})
```

navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

export const Navbar = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.padding}>
      <View style={styles.navbar}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
        style={styles.button}

        >
          <Text>Todo</Text>  

        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity 
        style={styles.button}

        >
          <Text>Tags</Text>  
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you need to track the visiblity of what is visible in your state, 
in your **App** component, do this;

```
const [showTodos, setShowTodos] = useState(false);

const makeTodosInvisible= () => setShowTodos(false);
const makeTodosVisible = () => setShowTodos(true);

  return (
    <View>
      <Navbar onTodoPress={makeTodosVisible } onTagPress={makeTodosInvisible} title='Todo App!' />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {showTodos 
        ? <TodoScreen todos={todos} addTodo={addTodo} removeTodo={removeTodo} />
        :  <TagScreen addTags={addTags} tags={tags} removeTags={removeTags}/>
        }

        {/* <TodoScreen todos={todos} addTodo={addTodo} removeTodo={removeTodo} /> */}
        {/* HERE MUST CHANGED COMPONENTS */}
        </View>
    </View>
  )
```

and in your `navbar.js` do this

```
export const Navbar = ({ title, onTodoPress, onTagPress}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.padding}>
      <View style={styles.navbar}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
        style={styles.button}
         onPreesed={onTodoPress} // will hide Tags and show Todos
        >
          <Text>Todo</Text>  

        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity 
        style={styles.button}
   onPreesed={onTagPress} // will show Tags and hide Todos
        >
          <Text>Tags</Text>  
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very usefull comment. The new state was exatly what I needed, It work, but only when I change state by myself, entering true or falls and button still don't work, may be I need in new function in App, like addTodo.Can you help me with it?

Comment: what do you mean @IlyaKraevoy

Comment: I mean, when I change the state for true or false, I see changes, but buttons still don't work(

Comment: rename it to something you want, i also edited my code @IlyaKraevoy

Comment: Yes, I undestood, that I can rename it and I did it, but it didn't work. I use your finaly code and it also didn't work. I understand that logical is true, but I have no idea what's the problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ```onPreesed``` is not exist) ```onPress``` is exist) I can not find this mistake 2 dayes